# How do I merge/push a commit to a gitlab fork to the master repository

Tags: git, merge, gitlab

I pointed out a metadata 'issue' with an app developer on GitHub, he agreed to the metadata update on his end, but said F-Droid handled their own metadata. I emailed the issue link to F-droid and they replied: submit a merge request on fdroiddata.

After I figured out what that meant, I forked fdroiddata on GitLab, git cloned my fork, and edited the app's metadata file. Git status shows the file as modified; I git push'd to GitLab.

I'm not understanding 'The New Merge Request' screen. I've had lots of google hits on here and elsewhere, but the language is helping me see the path forward.

I want to merge/push/pull my (forked fdroiddata git) single file metadata commit to the main fdroiddata git on GitLab ---how do I do this?

Answer (score 1):

If you have a fork and go to https://gitlab.com/fdroid/fdroiddata/merge_requests there is s a green `New Merge Request` button in the upper right corner.